# Connect Azure DevOps List Items to SharePoint List using Power Automate

Tags: azure-devops, sharepoint, automation, power-automate, issue-tracking

I would like to make a flow that will connect "work items" from azure devops to my sharepoint list using power automate. How can I transfer that data into sharepoint list using power automate? I want things such as: ID, title, description, status, priority, assigned to, date etc. Moreover, I would want the flow to  "sync" work items with sharepoint list, so that the data is updated, for ex. every hour.

How can I achieve that? Can anyone help?

I quite know how it works when it comes to queries, but not sure what is the best way to do it with work items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [another open dicussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78027556/sharepoint-issue-tracker-connection-with-azure-devops-bugs/78032539#78032539) of yours, I had been testing to use the workflows below. For certain fields like data type of `identity`, we may need to format the value before transfering bewteen platforms. Here are my samples for your reference.

- ###### Workflow1:

  When I created a new bug in Azure DevOps web UI, the workflow would create a new item in the SharePoint list; (See [Create a SharePoint list item when an Azure DevOps work item is created | Microsoft Power Automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/details/1f309980ed8911e6a0e7f98291dcd11a/create-a-sharepoint-list-item-when-an-azure-devops-work-item-is-created/))

  [image]
- ###### Workflow2:

  If I updated a bug in Azure DevOps, which already had an existing item in the SharePoint list, the workflow would update the corresponding item in the SharePoint list; (Use [Update SharePoint list item when linked work item is changed in DevOps | Microsoft Power Automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/details/5cb3c0a0ed8b11e6a0e7f98291dcd11a/update-sharepoint-list-item-when-linked-work-item-is-changed-in-devops/))
  [image]
- ###### Workflow3:

  When I edited the column values for an item in the SharePoint list, the workflow would update the fields of the corresponding bug in Azure DevOps;
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a template for that, try to check it: https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/details/1f309980ed8911e6a0e7f98291dcd11a/create-a-sharepoint-list-item-when-an-azure-devops-work-item-is-created/

[image]

Comment: 