# Sharepoint Issue Tracker connection with Azure Devops bugs

Tags: azure-devops, sharepoint, power-automate, powerapps

I'm looking to create a Power Automate flow that connects Azure DevOps bugs (work items) to a SharePoint issue tracker list. The flow should trigger when a bug is created or modified in Azure DevOps. It will retrieve bugs, create or update corresponding items in SharePoint, and ensure synchronization between the two platforms. User should be able to view and modify bug details like priority or status directly from the SharePoint list interface.

Additionally, I may set up flows triggered by changes made in SharePoint to update corresponding bugs in Azure DevOps.

Maybe someone has done something like this or similar?

Any guidance, screenshots or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, there is no built-in functionality to synchronize the Azure DevOps work items with SharePoint list items. You may take references to the following templates and my sample Power Automate workflows as a workaround.

Based on your requirement and description, I generated a simple SharePoint list like below, each of whose columns were designed to map with the Azure DevOps work item fields (`Title`, `ID`, `State`, `Priority`).

[image]

- ###### Workflow1:

  When I created a new bug in Azure DevOps web UI, the workflow would create a new item in the SharePoint list; (See [Create a SharePoint list item when an Azure DevOps work item is created | Microsoft Power Automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/details/1f309980ed8911e6a0e7f98291dcd11a/create-a-sharepoint-list-item-when-an-azure-devops-work-item-is-created/))

  [image]
- ###### Workflow2:

  If I updated a bug in Azure DevOps, which already had an existing item in the SharePoint list, the workflow would update the corresponding item in the SharePoint list; (Use [Update SharePoint list item when linked work item is changed in DevOps | Microsoft Power Automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/details/5cb3c0a0ed8b11e6a0e7f98291dcd11a/update-sharepoint-list-item-when-linked-work-item-is-changed-in-devops/))
  [image]
- ###### Workflow3:

  When I edited the column values for an item in the SharePoint list, the workflow would update the fields of the corresponding bug in Azure DevOps;
  [image]
- ###### Kindly be noted that

1. The Azure DevOps connecter in Power Automate is a premium connecter, which requires a premium license but is included in the 90-day free trial;
2. The bugs which are not in the SharePoint list cannot be created via the `workflow2`; for this, you may consider [exporting the existing bugs from Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops) into the SharePoint list first;
3. The workflows could work when modifying the bugs/items in web UI, but seem not working with bulk creating/editing via csv import.
4. Please test the workflows with your test environment before integrating with your production one.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a huge help. One more thing, how can I map AzureDevopsID with my Sharepoint List? I only decided to use the workflow to create and modify work items from the Sharepoint List level.

Comment: Hi there, I don't think it is possible to map the values in `ID` column of SharePoint list with those of the work item ids, since one ID is generated with an item creation in SharePoint list and one work item id is generated with a work item creation in Azure DevOps organization. Neither of the id values in a SharePoint List or in an Azure DevOps organization can be edited after creation. Therefore, instead of using the `ID`  column of the SharePoint list, we need to add a new column `WITID` in the SharePoint list to map with the values of Azure DevOps work item Ids.